# Flutter/Dart: Returning value from Switch/Case

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a date validator in my flutter application, using a switch case:

[Link to DartPad sample](https://dartpad.dev/c63f43cb4fe60a52243a01cab853b664)

```
class DateValidator {
  DateValidator({this.selectedDate, this.type});
  final String type;
  final DateTime selectedDate;


  dateValidator() {
    String _errorMsg = '';
    switch (type) {
      case "event":
        {
          if (selectedDate == null) _errorMsg = "No date selected";
          if (selectedDate == DateTime.now())
            _errorMsg = "Check your selected date";
        }
        break;

      case "test2":
        {
          print("test2");
        }
        break;

      default:
        {
          print("Invalid Date");
        }
        break;
    }

    return _errorMsg;
  }
}

void main() {
  DateValidator(
    selectedDate: DateTime.now(),
    type: 'event',
  ).dateValidator().then((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

I would like to then return _errorMsg like so:

```
DateValidator(type: widget.deal.date).dateValidator()
.then((errorMsg){
  print(errorMsg);
});
```

This results in:

> Class 'bool' has no instance method 'then'.

How can I correctly return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your:

```
dateValidator() {
```

With:

```
Future<String> dateValidator() async {
```

***Reason to do this:*** If you want to get your result in `then` method then you need to specify your method's return type as `Future<String>` because `then` is a method defined in `Future` class.